# Trying to run a docker container after successful image build

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

I have tried different versions of python and numpy but nothing seems to work. Also tried displaying 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' in the console and it worked fine for numpy version 1.19.3, 1.19.4 and 1.19.5 versions.

After the docker run command, it displays the following error:

```
(py36) C:\ANPR\Video_Tolling>docker run -p 5000:5000 dockerpython
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  from . import multiarray
 File "/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
  from . import overrides
 File "/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
  from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  import video_toll
 File "/video_toll.py", line 2, in <module>
  from calculations import Calculations
 File "/calculations.py", line 3, in <module>
  import numpy as np
 File "/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
  from . import core
 File "/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
  raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

* The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/usr/local/bin/python"
* The NumPy version is: "1.19.3"
and make sure that they are the versions you expect.

Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

`Requirements.txt` has the following requirements:

```
Flask==1.1.1
requests~=2.25.1
opencv-python~=4.5.1.48
imutils~=0.5.3
numpy~=1.19.4
pytesseract~=0.3.7
pyzbar~=0.1.8
pandas~=1.2.1
pymongo~=3.11.2
publicip~=1.0.1
dnspython
```

My Conda environment has:

```
numpy version 1.19.4
python version 3.8
```

Docker File:

```
FROM python:3.8.0-buster

# Make a directory for our application
WORKDIR ./
# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy our source code
COPY /app .

# Run the application
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Comment: Show us your `Dockerfile`!

Comment: @KlausD.  
'
FROM python:3.8.0-buster

# Make a directory for our application
    WORKDIR ./
# Install dependencies
   COPY requirements.txt .
   RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy our source code
   COPY /app .

# Run the application
   CMD ["python", "main.py"]
'

Comment: Add it to the question!

Comment: @KlausD. Added.

Comment: Probably something interesting happened during `docker build` but we'd need to see those logs too.

Comment: What puzzles me is the location on `numpy`. Do you have a package `numpy` in your project folder?

Comment: @KlausD.
Yeah there is a numpy in video/tolling/venv/lib/site-packages/

Comment: That's not what your traceback shows: `File "/numpy/__init__.py"`

Comment: @KlausD. so what do i do now

Comment: Well, how does that folder get there?

Comment: @KlausD. I don't know it is the work of another developer

Comment: Any reason why you're using python 3.8.0? There's a python 3.8.10-buster available on docker hub.